# Asymptotic of isospectral matrix flow, for $t\to\infty$

Tags: matrices, asymptotics, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras, hamilton-equations

I have an isospectral flow on $\mathfrak{su}(N)$, for some $N>1$ of the form:
$$
\dot{W}=\left[ LW,W\right],
$$
where $W\in\mathfrak{su}(N)$ and, introducing the Frobenius inner product $\langle A,B\rangle_F=Tr(A^*B)$, $L$ is an invertible positive definite Frobenius self-adjoint linear map on $\mathfrak{su}(N)$.

At $t=0$, assume that $LW$ and $W$ do not commute:
$$
\left[ LW,W\right](0)\neq 0.
$$
Is it possible to prove that
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\|\left[ LW,W\right](t)\|>0 ?
$$
The spectrum $\sigma(W)$ and the energy $H(W) = -1/2 Tr(LW^*W)$ are first integrals of motion.